# Ubuntu 16 on Hyper v screen flicker and other problems

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v

I installed ubuntu 16 64bit on windows 10 hyper-v. I allocated 2gb ram and 10gb HDD space which is enough for a plain ubuntu installation.

The installation completed successfully. But I do not see the unity sidebar launcher.

There is a considerable lag when I move the mouse cursor and the screen seems to be flickering as shown in the gif. Notice the folder in the gif flicker. Note that the flicker is not due to the fact that this is a gif.

[image]

I tried using virtual box and it worked fine but as I am using Hyper-v with other development software I am unable to run VirtuaBox alongside Hyper-v.

**Kindly suggest how can I run ubuntu on windows 10**.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, Hyper-V is best suited for server systems, and for cases like this [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) is a good alternative.